# Communication between two Elastic Beanstalk applications on same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two beanstalk applications which are on the same VPC. How do I use APIs on one from the other without going over the internet? I have the private IPs for the instances in those applications, but it doesn't seem right to access the instances directly. I should be accessing the application.

Answer (score 2):

Elastic Beanstalk will replace your instances and change the IPs. And it doesn't sound too scalable anyway.
If you want the other server to perform some action offline (e.g. synch some data), than the recommended approach is via a Queue. One server posts to a queue, and the other listens to it (SQS).
If it's an online operation (e.g. API call), than I suggest setting up another EB environment and using its URL. It won't go via the internet if it's the same AWS zone.

Comment: "It won't go via the internet if it's the same AWS zone". I could not find this mentioned anywhere. Can you point me to some place where this is described?

Comment: that's how AWS routing works. give it a try. trace route the url